# How to generate a bibliography with pandoc?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, pandoc

How can I generate a bibliography with pandoc?

If I have this test.md file:

```
# Test

This is a test [@doe1905].

# Bibliography
```

How can I generate the bibliography with this bibtex reference:

```
@article{doe1905,
 author={Doe, John},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={1905},
}
```

I have tried to add it to test.bib and run pandoc with `pandoc --bibliography=test.bib -o test.pdf test.md` but that did not create a bibliography in the resulting test.pdf.

Running `pandoc --bibliography=test.bib -o test.tex test.md` gives me this, where the bibliography seems to be included:

```
\hypertarget{test}{%
\section{Test}\label{test}}

This is a test {[}@doe1905{]}.

\hypertarget{bibliography}{%
\section{Bibliography}\label{bibliography}}
```

**Solution:**

I was able to generate the bibliography by adding --citeproc:

`pandoc --bibliography=test.bib --citeproc -o test.pdf test.md`

Comment: For me your test files with the specified command line work without problems, i.e., a bibliography is printed in the pdf. Do you get any errors in the terminal? Maybe `--log=logfile.txt` or `--verbose` displays a warning or error? Could you add the generated `.tex` file (from `--verbose` or, alternatively, by running `-o test.tex` instead of `-o test.pdf`) to your question?

Comment: hi @Marijn, thanks four your comment. I was able to create the bibliography by simply adding --citeproc

Comment: Good to hear that the problem is solved. According to the Q&A-model of this site it would be better to add you solution as an answer to your own question instead of an edit, though.

Comment: yes, of course :)

Comment: The important bit for me was to add citations as `[@doe1905]`, not as `\cite{doe1905}` and to use the `--biliography=` flag, not set up biblatex in my style file.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to generate the bibliography by adding --citeproc:

`pandoc --bibliography=test.bib --citeproc -o test.pdf test.md`

Comment: In pandoc versions prior to 2.11 (in 2022, `apt-get install pandoc` installs v2.5), `--citeproc` must be replaced with `--filter pandoc-citeproc`, perhaps after running `apt-get install pandoc-citeproc`.